# Отправить Multipart Form используя requests. Python

Tags: python, requests

Задача отправить такой же запрос из python скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В header запрос таков

```
headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
         'Accept':'application/json',
         'Authorization':'Bearer'})
```

Он отправляется успешно, данные приходят в json формате, но вот форма будто вовсе не отправляется.
Какой бы я из параметров не использовал (data или files), в ответе получаю:

```
{"error":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."}
```

Также пробовал использовать MultipartEncoder из модуля requests_toolbelt, но это так же безуспешно.

Пробую так:

```
req = requests.post(url, 
                files =  {'grand_type': 'authorization_code',
                               'client_id': '1488',
                               'client_secret': '<mycode>',
                               'redirect_uri': 'https://example.com',
                               'code':'<mycode>'},
                headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
                         'Accept':'application/json',
                         'Authorization':'Bearer'}
                )

print(req.text)
```

UPD: Чтобы не было путаницы, что указывать в header, ниже фото того, что отправляю и что оно работает и изменять его нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обычно, в 'Authorization': должен быть 'Bearer <ваш токен>', не просто Bearer...

Comment: Для проверки реквестов я использую insomnia, та что на фото. В ней сервер отвечает правильно с 'Authorization':'Bearer'

Comment: data тоже ожидается, как json? попробуйте data = json(словарь с grand_type и т.д.)?

Comment: Пробовал, это также не работает.

Comment: отредактировал выше

Comment: data ожидается как Form

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117978/discussion-between-betepok-and-jack-os).